# Why did I get more than 200 rep in one day?

Tags: support, reputation

Why did I get yesterday [239 rep](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/90802/j-doe?tab=reputation) for the [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/116756/how-can-i-protect-myself-from-fallout-with-my-employer-over-my-political-blog) I asked?

I think the daily maximum rep you can get is only 200 (apart from few exceptions like when you get your answer accepted or when you get a bounty), or am I mistaken?

Comment: Don't be greedy ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You received a 100 rep association bonus yesterday for joining the site.

Look at the "reputation" tab on your own [profile screen](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/90802/j-doe) and you'll see the break-down of where your rep comes from:

[image]

See, you got the Association bonus yesterday and a bunch of upticks.

You can also get over 200 per day if you get a tagged answer (15 per answer) or you receive a bounty.

See also [What is reputation and how can I earn it?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from the combination of upvotes, downvotes and suggested edits. But Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to this daily reputation limit.

Comment: Accepted answers also ignore the rep cap (as I recently found out - twice :) )